# jQuery is not defined in Angular 8 in StackBlitz

Tags: jquery, angular, angular8, stackblitz

package json

```
             "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.x",
        "@types/select2": "^4.0.x",
        "core-js": "2.6.9",
        "jquery": "^3.4.x",
        "ng-select2": "^1.1.2",
        "rxjs": "6.5.2",
        "select2": "^4.0.x",
        "zone.js": "0.9.1"
         }
```

app module.ts

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import * as jquery from 'jquery';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

    import { NgSelect2Module } from 'ng-select2';
    @NgModule({
      imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,NgSelect2Module ],
      declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
      bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qsa8le?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-select2/v/1.1.2

- i have checked Jquery is Installed as dependencies.
- any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: declare var $; try this

Comment: whaere to declare in code please can you help

Comment: in `angular-cli.json` file add jquery to scripts like `"scripts": [ "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]` and then try your same code

Comment: @afeef just above the NgModule, but add the code Dheeraj suggested to angular-cli.json too

Comment: add @DheerajKumar but why u need jquery ? you can do everything you want with no jquery. Add jquery to an angular project is odd.

Comment: i need jquery  for https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-select2/v/1.1.2

Comment: already added in depedencies

Comment: [this select2](https://github.com/Harvest-Dev/ng-select2) for Angular doesn't require jQuery

Comment: Just for the suggestion, I think 'ng-select2'  has an issue with its dependency, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown for your purpose.

I have used it in many of my projects.